# Weird KL divergence behaviour

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, variational-autoencoder

I'm training a complex model for motion prediction using a VAE, however the KL divergence has a very strange behavior[image].

A scheleton of the network is the following:

[image]

At the end my network compute the MSE loss of the trajectory and the Kullback Leibler loss (with gaussian prior with mean 0 and std equal to 1) given as:

```
kld_loss = -0.5*torch.sum(1 + sigma - mu.pow(2) - sigma.exp())
```

Any idea of the possible causes? Do you need further details?

Comment: Yes, do need further details.

Comment: Added more details @Kostya